# Why are async state machines classes (and not structs) in Roslyn?

Tags: c#, .net, language-lawyer, roslyn

Let’s consider this very simple async method:

```
static async Task myMethodAsync() 
{
    await Task.Delay(500);
}
```

When I compile this with VS2013 (pre Roslyn compiler) the generated state-machine is a struct.

```
private struct <myMethodAsync>d__0 : IAsyncStateMachine
{  
    ...
    void IAsyncStateMachine.MoveNext()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

When I compile it with VS2015  (Roslyn) the generated code is this:

```
private sealed class <myMethodAsync>d__1 : IAsyncStateMachine
{
    ...
    void IAsyncStateMachine.MoveNext()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

As you can see Roslyn generates a class (and not a struct). If I remember correctly the first implementations of the async/await support in the old compiler (CTP2012 i guess) also generated classes and then it was changed to struct from performance reasons. (in some cases you can completely avoid boxing and heap allocation…) (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23609110/why-are-awaiters-async-await-structs-and-not-classes-can-classes-be-used))

Does anyone know why this was changed again in Roslyn? (I don’t have any problem regarding this, I know that this change is transparent and does not change the behavior of any code, I’m just curious)

**Edit:**

The answer from @Damien_The_Unbeliever (and the source code :) ) imho explains everything. The described behaviour of Roslyn only applies for debug build (and that's needed because of the CLR limitation mentioned in the comment). In Release it also generates a struct (with all the benefits of that..). So this seems to be a very clever solution to support both Edit and Continue and better performance in production. Interesting stuff, thanks for everyone who participated!

Comment: I suspect that they decided the complexity (re mutable structs) wasn't worth it. `async` methods almost always have a true asynchronous point - an `await` that yields control, which would require the struct to be boxed anyway. I *believe* structs would only relieve memory pressure for `async` methods that happened to run synchronously.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

I didn't have any foreknowledge of this, but since Roslyn is open-source these days, we can go hunting through the code for an explanation.

And here, on [line 60 of the AsyncRewriter](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/e6a3ec3348ccdf25083d43502bf42519429148f2/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Lowering/AsyncRewriter/AsyncRewriter.cs#L60), we find:

```
// The CLR doesn't support adding fields to structs, so in order to enable EnC in an async method we need to generate a class.
var typeKind = compilationState.Compilation.Options.EnableEditAndContinue ? TypeKind.Class : TypeKind.Struct;
```

So, whilst there's some appeal to using `struct`s, the big win of allowing [Edit and Continue](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2015/02/23/edit-and-continue-and-make-object-id-improvements-in-ctp-6.aspx) to work within `async` methods was obviously chosen as the better option.

Comment: Very good catch! And based on this here is what I also discovered: This only happens when you build it in debug (makes sense, that's when you do EnC..), but in Release they create a struct (obviously EnableEditAndContinue is false in that case...). Btw. I also tried looking into the code, but did not find this. Many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It's hard to give a definitive answer for something like this (unless someone from the compiler team drops in :)), but there's a few points you can consider:

The performance "bonus" of structs is always a tradeoff. Basically, you get the following:

- Value semantics
- Possible stack (maybe even register?) allocation
- Avoiding indirection

What does this mean in the await case? Well, actually... nothing. There's only a very short time period during which the state machine is on the stack - remember, `await` effectively does a `return`, so the method stack dies; the state machine must be preserved somewhere, and that "somewhere" is definitely on the heap. Stack lifetime doesn't fit asynchronous code well :)

Apart from this, the state machine violates some good guidelines for defining structs:

- `struct`s should be at most 16-bytes large - the state machine contains two pointers, which on their own fill the 16-byte limit neatly on 64-bit. Apart from that, there's the state itself, so it goes over the "limit". This is not a *big* deal, since it's quite likely only ever passed by reference, but note how that doesn't quite fit the use case for structs - a struct that's basically a reference type.
- `struct`s should be immutable - well, this probably doesn't need much of a comment. It's a *state machine*. Again, this is not a big deal, since the struct is auto-generated code and private, but...
- `struct`s should logically represent a single value. Definitely not the case here, but that already kind of follows from having a mutable state in the first place.
- It shouldn't be boxed frequently - not a problem here, since we're using generics *everywhere*. The state is ultimately somewhere on the heap, but at least it's not being boxed (automatically). Again, the fact that it's only used internally makes this pretty much void.

And of course, all this is in a case where there's no closures. When you have locals (or fields) that traverse the `await`s, the state is further inflated, limiting the usefulness of using a struct.

Given all this, the class approach is definitely cleaner, and I wouldn't expect any noticeable performance increase from using a `struct` instead. All of the objects involved have similar lifetime, so the only way to improve memory performance would be to make *all* of them `struct`s (store in some buffer, for example) - which is impossible in the general case, of course. And most cases where you'd use `await` in the first place (that is, some asynchronous I/O work) already involve other classes - for example, data buffers, strings... It's rather unlikely you would `await` something that simply returns `42` without doing any heap allocations.

In the end, I'd say the only place where you'd really see a real performance difference would be benchmarks. And optimizing for benchmarks is a silly idea, to say the least...

Comment: You don't always *need* a member of the compiler team when you can go and read the source, and they've left a helpful comment :-)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yeah, that was definitely a great find, I already upvoted your answer :P

Comment: The struct helps a lot in the case that the code does not run async, e.g. the data is already in a buffer.